# R roxygen2: Do not show function in list

Tags: r, r-package, cran, roxygen2

This question is about using **roxygen2** and not about how to override a function.

I am using **roxygen2** for a CRAN package and I am trying to achieve the following:

There is a function called `my.function` whose function name I want to replace with `my_function`.

I want to do this gradually - so for some time both functions names shall be available.

For a first step I'd like to have the following:

1. If a user explicitly calls `?my.function` they shall come to the documentation of `my.function` function (or to the documentation of my_function)
2. But if a user calls `help(package="myPackage")` `my.function` shall not appear in the functions list

The background is, if a user explicitly searches for the old function name, they will still find it. But if they are just generally searching for available functions (because they are new to the package) they will only get to new name.

How can I do this?

I was experimenting with combinations of the following roxygen tags:

```
@noRd
@alias
@describeIn
@rdname
```

But I was not able to achieve my desired result. I am asking specifically about the roxgen2 documentation part, not about overriding a function in R in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: what's the proper way to overwrite a function from a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644680/r-whats-the-proper-way-to-overwrite-a-function-from-a-package)

Comment: Can't find the exact question but I've seen one before in the past. Here's another:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921304/r-package-development-overriding-a-function-from-one-package-with-a-function-fr?rq=1

Comment: The best way to do this is to insert a call to `.Deprecated` in `my.function`, so that anyone who uses it will automatically see that it's deprecated without having to check the help.

Comment: Thanks for your hints Nelson. I edited the question to make this clearer - the question was not about a function override - but about roxygen settings for creating documentation. Think the answer of Joris and the comment of Hong should solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable functions from being listed in the package manual by adding `@keywords internal` to the roxygen comments (see e.g. the **Object documentation** section of [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/)), but as mentioned by Hong Ooi the proper way is probably to deprecate `my.function` (see the **Releasing a package** section of [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/)).

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the answer I was searching for. Also thanks for the additional link.